# Problema al borrar Foreign Key en SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli, table, server

estoy haciendo una base de datos (videojuegos) con 3 tablas (consolas, estudios y juegos), la tabla juegos tiene dos claves foráneas, una que referencia a consolas y otra a estudios.

Las creo:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONSOLAS (NOMCONSOLA VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY, ID INT);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ESTUDIOS (NOMESTUDIO VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY, ID INT)";

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS JUEGOS ( NOMJUEGO VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY, NOMCONSOLA VARCHAR(50), NOMESTUDIO VARCHAR(50), FOREIGN KEY (NOMCONSOLA) REFERENCES CONSOLAS(NOMCONSOLA) ON DELETE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY (NOMESTUDIO) REFERENCES estudios(NOMESTUDIO) ON DELETE CASCADE);

Pero si intento eliminar por ejemplo la tabla ESTUDIOS no me deja, uso lo siguiente:

ALTER TABLE JUEGOS DROP FOREIGN KEY NOMESTUDIO

Y no me hace nada, dice que no encuentra la clave foránea. Estoy desesperado

#1091 - No puedo eliminar (DROP FOREIGN KEY) `nomconsola`. compuebe que el campo/clave existe

¿Alguna solución? Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: borra la constraint de llave foránea

Comment: Y como la borro?, si eso mismo es lo que no me deja hacer

Comment: NOMCONSOLA **NO** es el nombre de la foreign key, es el nombre del campo restringido. Busca en el diccionario de datos de la BD el nombre de la foreign key (que se le habrá puesto de forma automática)

Comment: ¿Como logro sacar el diccionario de datos de la BD?

Comment: Esto es SQL, MySQL ??? por que en PHPMYADMIN puedes leer las foraneas de inmediato

Comment: Uso SQL, ¿donde puedo leer las claves foraneas?